# GCP Cloud Composer access Airflow UI with token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-webserver, google-cloud-composer-2

Is there a way on GCP Cloud Composer to access Airflow UI without GCP/Google account only with constructing the link with some kind of token.

AWS has it implemented [this way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/call-mwaa-apis-web.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=YOUR_HOST_NAME
YOUR_URL=https://$HOST/aws_mwaa/aws-console-sso?login=true#
WEB_TOKEN=$(aws mwaa create-web-login-token --name YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME --query WebToken --output text)
echo $YOUR_URL$WEB_TOKEN
```

Bash, python or any other solution would be very helpful.

So far I managed to get Airflow UI URL from gcloud cli:

`gcloud composer environments describe ENVIRONMENT_NAME --location=LOCATION --format "value(config.airflowUri)"`

Comment: A similar command is `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token You can use the returned token in your scripts.

Comment: The idea is to pass redirect url with token to user and skip logging in with google account to Cloud Composer Airflow UI.

Do you have any suggestions how would I use access or id token in this case?

Comment: I don't know the details of authorization for Airflow UI. My previous comment is to show a similar command to the one in your post.